# What does "spring up here" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of this sentence:

> To wish a vital urban life might somehow **spring up here** is to play with day dreams.

I understand the meaning of individual words, I just cannot understand it grammatically.

Comment: Have you tried searching the Internet for "spring up define", as in [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="spring+up+define")?

Comment: Think of a dandelion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it up into parts:

> To wish
>
> a vital urban life
>
> might somehow **spring up here**
>
> is to play with day dreams.

Here's what we've got:

1. Wishing that
2. a place teeming with cafes, night life, and bohemians ...
3. might one day **suddenly arise here**, replacing whatever is here today ...
4. is exactly like wishing that a silly day dream might one day come true.

***Spring up here*** means ***suddenly arise here***.

Answer (score 0):

To spring up here is referring to an old English saying. A farmer who is on his pink cloud might buy land totally wrong for his crops. When another farmer hears about the purchase or obtaining of land, they would say "you think wheat will spring up here" ?!! It is a sarcastic remark to emphasize low chance of success.

Comment: It is not a sarcastic remark if one doesn't use it that way.

Comment: "Spring up" simply refers to plants sprouting out of the ground.  It carries no connotation, positive or negative.